# Angular 2 e2e protactor: If I don't use browser.sleep(), my test fails. Why?

Tags: angular, protractor

I am writing some e2e tests, and when filling out a form and trying to select items in a custom select dropdown component I made, I am being forced to use `browser.sleep(...)` for my test to work, and if I don't use it then the test fails. Why is this happening?

This is the working test:

```
describe('...', () => {
    it(`...`, () => {
        page.navigateTo('/...').then(() => {
            element(by.tagName('single-select-foo')).element(by.tagName('button')).click().then(() => {
                element(by.tagName('single-select-foo')).all(by.css('.select-menu-item')).first().click();
            });

            browser.sleep(2000);

            element(by.tagName('single-select-bar')).element(by.tagName('button')).click().then(() => {
                element(by.tagName('single-select-bar')).all(by.css('.select-menu-item')).first().click();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This is the failing test (removed `browser.slepe(2000)` line:

```
describe('...', () => {
    it(`...`, () => {
        page.navigateTo('/...').then(() => {
            element(by.tagName('single-select-foo')).element(by.tagName('button')).click().then(() => {
                element(by.tagName('single-select-foo')).all(by.css('.select-menu-item')).first().click();
            });

            element(by.tagName('single-select-bar')).element(by.tagName('button')).click().then(() => {
                element(by.tagName('single-select-bar')).all(by.css('.select-menu-item')).first().click();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The failing test gives me this error:

> - Failed: unknown error: Element `<button _ngcontent-c16="" class="btn btn--select" type="button">...</button>` is not clickable at point
>     (514, 439). Other element would receive the click: ...
>     (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5
>     x86_64)

Comment: Probably the sleep allows the page to finish rendering and without it protractor is trying to interact with an element that is not fully there yet. I have the same issue with chromedriver in general on other platforms.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Do you know of a more beautiful way to write this then? Like is there some kind of promise or something I can listen for and chain the things together instead of doing an unpredictable `browser.sleep()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by actually working around the specific error in code. Leveraged `browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(...))` on that `button` element in the error and problem solved, since the error said that button is not clickable at the point the error occurred.